# How can I use a JS value (timezone) in PHP before page loads?

Tags: javascript, php

I am displaying dates on a website that will be used by users from different countries. From what I understand the only reliable way to determine user's timezone is via javascript (I used this https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect/). If that matters I'm using Yii.

Now I can use javascript to automatically select a proper timezone in a `<select>` element during registration. The problem is however, that I will be showing them to anonymous users as well... on the home page. So it looks like the timezone will have to be taken from javascript and stored either in a cookie or in session data. I could implement a sloppy solution (for example use UTC on first page load). But that will confuse first time visitors and cookies/sessions aren't stored forever anyway so the problem would reoccur even for returning users.

I can imagine a few ways to do this:

1. If the value is not set I could force the framework to send a blank page containing just a simple script that will ajax the value back to the server and then refresh.
2. Alternatively I could force a redirect to a page that will ajax and then redirect back.
3. Not sure if possible, but I think I could echo the javascript, ajax the value and wipe document's content. Meanwhile pause PHP and check every 1s if the session variable changed in db (or wherever else it is stored). After getting the timezone I resume PHP's work and send the true content.
4. This one I like even less. Instead of outputting actual dates i could output something like `<span class="timestamp>1750411</span>` and then use js to alter the content of all ".timestamp".
5. Alternatively `<span class="UTC">*UTC DATETIME HERE*</span>` and then using js adjust the hour/day as necessary. While a much better solution (dates display with js turned off) that however could prove difficult on DST change days.

Problem is that I believe using any of the first 3 would break the page for crawlers and those aren't really neat solutions anyway. Thoughts? Ideas? How are pages like facebook doing it?

Comment: geolocation databases. "this is IP is in country X, province Y, city Z, therefore it's timezone PQR". still fails for people using vpns/proxies, but good 'nuff for most cases.

Comment: I guess that works. Didn't know geoip can return a timezone. Thanks, if you're gonna post it as an answer I will mark it.

Comment: I wouldn't say a geoip db would have timezone data, but once you've got a location, it'd be trivial to lookup what the timezone for that location is.